# RadarChart with Sqlite Android Studio using nested loop

Tags: java, loops, sqlite

I am struggling with this radar chart. I want to put every customer in the radar chart.  Only one appears, and all the value for the others are added for this single customer. Can someone help me please?

```java
private void setupChartView() {
       RadarChart radarChart = findViewById(R.id.radarChart);

        ArrayList<RadarEntry> dataEntries = new ArrayList<>();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor getCustomer = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT " + C_SALES_CUSTOMER + " FROM " + TABLESALES, null);

        for(int i=0; i<getCustomer.getCount(); i++) {

            getCustomer.moveToNext();
            @SuppressLint("Range")
            String customer =  getCustomer.getString(getCustomer.getColumnIndex(C_SALES_CUSTOMER));

            Cursor getSales = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLESALES + " where " + C_SALES_CUSTOMER + " like '%" + customer + "%'", null);
            for(int j=0; j<getSales.getCount(); j++) {
                getSales.moveToNext();
                @SuppressLint("Range")
                String sales =  getSales.getString(getSales.getColumnIndex(C_SALES_TOTAL));
                RadarEntry radarEntry = new RadarEntry(Integer.valueOf(sales));
                dataEntries.add(radarEntry);

                RadarDataSet radarDataSet = new RadarDataSet(dataEntries, customer);
                RadarData radarData = new RadarData();
                radarData.addDataSet(radarDataSet);
                radarChart.setData(radarData);
            }
        }
        radarChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

        Legend legend = radarChart.getLegend();
        legend.setXEntrySpace(7f);
        legend.setYEntrySpace(5f);
        legend.setYOffset(75f);
        legend.setTextSize(16f);
        legend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself

```
private void setupChartView() {
    RadarChart radarChart = findViewById(R.id.radarChart);
    RadarData radarData = new RadarData();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor getCustomer = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT " + C_SALES_CUSTOMER + " FROM " + TABLESALES, null);

    for(int i=0; i<getCustomer.getCount(); i++) {
        ArrayList<RadarEntry> dataEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        getCustomer.moveToNext();
        @SuppressLint("Range")
        String customer =  getCustomer.getString(getCustomer.getColumnIndex(C_SALES_CUSTOMER));
        Cursor getSales = db.rawQuery("select " + C_SALES_TOTAL + " from " + TABLESALES + " where " + C_SALES_CUSTOMER + " = '" + customer + "'", null);
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(getSales.getCount()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for(int j=0; j<getSales.getCount(); j++) {

            getSales.moveToNext();
            @SuppressLint("Range")
            String sales =  getSales.getString(getSales.getColumnIndex(C_SALES_TOTAL));
            Toast.makeText(this, sales, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            RadarEntry radarEntry = new RadarEntry(Integer.valueOf(sales));
            dataEntries.add(radarEntry);
        }
        RadarDataSet radarDataSet = new RadarDataSet(dataEntries, customer);
        int color= ((int)(Math.random()*16777215)) | (0xFF << 24);
        radarDataSet.setColor(color);
        radarData.addDataSet(radarDataSet);
    }

    radarChart.setData(radarData);
    radarChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

    Legend legend = radarChart.getLegend();
    legend.setXEntrySpace(7f);
    legend.setYEntrySpace(5f);
    legend.setYOffset(75f);
    legend.setTextSize(16f);
    legend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
}
```